# How to convert a string in variable in shell

Tags: shell, csh

```
set lamdrills = ("drill_1-2" drill_2-3")
set drill_1_2_fill_layers = ("cvf1") #input from other files
set span = `echo "$lam_drl" | cut -f2 -d'_'`
set startspan = `echo "$span" | cut -f1 -d'-'`
set endspan = `echo "$span" | cut -f2 -d'-'`
set fill_layers = `echo drill_"$startspan"_"$endspan"_fill_layers`
```

I want assign the drill_1_2_fill_layers to the fill_layers

Comment: Yes. I am using .csh file. set drill_1_2_fill_layers = ("cvf1") set drill_2_3_fill_layers  = ("cvf2" ) was in another file and i was calling this file in another script. But based on lamdrills values, the fill layers values to assigned.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. If you want to `set fill_layers = $drill_1_2_fill_layers` why don't you just do that?

Comment: There's a quote missing, apparently you mean `set lamdrills = ("drill_1-2" "drill_2-3")` ... and probably `set span = \`echo "$lamdrills" | cut -f2 -d'_'\` `?

Comment: For "drill_1-2" lamdrill, i want to assign fill_layers as $drill_1_2_fill_layers and for "drill_2-3" lamdrill,  i want to assign fill_layers as $drill_2_3_fill_layers. And another example, if lamdrill was drill_6-7, i want assign ill_layers as $drill_6_7_fill_layers. here startspan was 6 and endspan was 7. So that i had created fill layers from lamdrills. Now as per above code, fill_layers variable assigned as "drill_1_2_fill_layers" [string] not "cvf1"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to update it. Probably also fix the typos I reported unless those were the actual problem you were trying to ask about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks vaguely like you are looking for

```csh
set lamdrills = ("drill_1-2" "drill_2-3")  # typo fixed
foreach drill ($lamdrills)                 # loop over array
  set fill_layers = drill_`echo $drill | sed 's/.*_//;s/-/_/'`_fill_layers
  # ... use this variable
end
```

The C shell is tricky and unpopular ([for good reasons](https://www.mars.org/home/rob/docs/csh-whynot.html)); perhaps you would like to use a Bourne-compatible shell instead?

```sh
for drill in "drill_1-2" "drill_2-3"; do
  fill_layers="drill_$(echo "$drill" | sed 's/.*_//;s/-/_/')_fill_layers"
  # ... use "$fill_layers"
done
```

Of course, even better would be if the labels you use would use the same conventions and punctuation patterns consistently.

Comment: set fill_layers = drill_`echo $drill | sed 's/.*_//;s/-/_/`_fill_layers. this line helps me to create "drill_1_2_fill_layers" name. But not able assign the "drill_1_2_fill_layers" values [cvf1] to the fill_layers.

Comment: If one day you can spell out in your question what you actually want to ask, perhaps it will be clear enough that I can understand and answer that too.  If you have a new question, probably (accept this answer and) ask a new question.